# SSR vs CSR explanation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I've been working as a full stack web developer for over a year now. Nextjs/golang is our stack. Today I realized that I have no idea whether we use CSR or SSR. I think we use CSR but I'm not sure. I've gone down rabbitholes on this topic like 100 times but its never stuck.

First question:
When they say server side, do they mean on the backend? i.e. golang? or does that mean on the nextjs server? Whenever someone says server I think backend but I don't think this is correct.

Second question:
How does client side rendering work? Like I know the server sends javascript to the client then the client uses the javascript to build the page. But all of this javascript must make a bunch of requests to the server to grab data and html right? Like how would the javascript build the page otherwise? Is this why react/nextjs is written in jsx? So the server can send all the JSX which is actually just javascript to the client then the client can build the html?

Third Question:
If CSR has the client build the page, how would this ever work? Like what about all of the data that needs to be pulled from our database for specific users / etc etc. That can't be done directly from the frontend.

I tried reading tons of articles online! Hasn't clicked yet

Answer (score 2):

CSR - server sends HTML that contains links to javascript (`script` tags). Clients then loads and executes JS (JavaScript typically contains fetching code). That means that each client will perform several round trips to the server to get HTML and then the data.

SSR - server sends HTML and embeds the necessary data in it
[image]

The client already has the data and HTML, so it can render it. SSR does fetch **on each request,** meaning the client still gets the latest data.
Benefits of using SSR compared to CSR is lower load time, it makes the website feel "faster" and also improves the ranking by search engine bots. On the other hand, the server does the rendering, which increases its burden (though fewer requests decreases it).

SSG is the same as SSR but **fetching occurs at build time**, the result page is computed only once and returned for each request. It is possible to use SSG with or without data.

Use SSG if possible, then mostly SSR. In some occasions it may be better to use CSR instead of SSR, though I'm not experienced enough to give the answer when.

Now answering your questions:

1. Yes, SSR happens on the server. If you use `fetch` function then it will work on client. But if you use `getServerSideProps` or `getStatisSideProps` then it will work on server. You can read from the file system, `fetch` public API or query the database, whatever you do in `getStatisSideProps`, `getServerSideProps` will run on the server, before returning the response.
2. Yes, you're correct. Client need the data to render the page, so it has to send requests to server and then render.
3. The third question is the same as the second. I hope the long answer I gave clarified your confusion.

Sorry for long answer.

Answer (score 0):

You said the essential thing yourself:  in client-side rendering, ***"the server sends javascript to the client, then the client uses the javascript to build the page."***  Hold on to that one point – everything else is secondary. **The** ***client*** **"renders."**

Now that "client-side" rendering capabilities have become so powerful – and, so *varied* – it has generally become favored.  If you "tell the client what to do and then let **him** do it," you are more likely to get a consistently favorable outcome for most clients.  Yes, the client will issue perhaps-many AJAX requests in carrying out your instructions. That is irrelevant.